# Rails user list from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following mhartl's tutorial at ruby.railstutorial.org and I'm having an issue with the index function of the users_controller.  In the console, I can enter this code:

```
@users = User.all
```

and it properly accesses the SQL database and displays the list of all users.  However, when I try to load the page I get various errors depending on how I use the list in the index file, but all involving the list being nil.  For example, if my index page contains this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

The server spits out:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Something like `render @users` gives me the error of `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.`

I am really confused why I would get this error if it works in the console.  Let me know if you need some other code from me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, possibly interesting.  The prompt running the rails server spits this out just before the `nil` error is produced:

    `Started GET "/users" for ...`
    `Processing by UsersController#index as HTML`
    `... SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '...' LIMIT 1`

So it seems like it's retrieving only the users with a specific cookie token, but I guess it doesn't exist?  Any idea why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All this error messages indicate that @user is nil in your view.
Assuming the view is views/users/index.html.erb, *have* you initialized @users in your users_controller index action like this?

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I have that.  But somehow it isn't actually putting anything into `@users`, even though the exact same code works fine from the console.

Comment: never seen that failing. you should check very closely if you missed something, or provide your controller and view code here for further inspection.

Comment: Sigh...as usual, I'm ashamed to admit what the problem was.  Somehow I had an additional empty `index` method in my controller that was completely throwing it off.  And then I was missing the user partial, so I had to fix that.  But now everything is working!  Your suggestion to check closely, which I thought I had done, paid off.  Thank you :)